# Mega and elementary OS Loki

Tags: release-loki

I can't run megasync on elementary OS Loki Beta 2.

The elementary OS client here (https://mega.nz/#sync) is for Freya and It has some conflict with libcrypto.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 Client, the log says Started but the folder doesn't sync and I can't see any GUI window.

Debug file: http://pastebin.com/EuG33Dvp

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer your question, but why would you trust your data to Kim Schmitz / Mega? He is a convicted criminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new version on their site for Loki, GUI is working. However, you still have to install the libcrypto dependency (`sudo apt install -f`).